# Conditional formatting based on values in current column of a Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I have a Table with three columns:

`Name      Task      Hours`
`Sheena    Task1     5`
`Sheena    Task2     3`
`Chris     Task1     5`
`Chris     Task1     2.5`

I am trying to conditionally format the `Hours` column. I want to format the cells there if the total hours for the person are over `7.5` . In the example, the cells containing the hours for `Sheena` should be formatted because her totals are over `7.5` but `Chris`'s equal exactly `7.5` so should not be formatted.

I assume the formula is something along these lines:

```
=SUMIF([Name],INDIRECT("RC[-2]",0),[Hours])>7.5
```

but this does not work. The following does:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,$A2,$C$2:$E$5)>7.5
```

but is messy because it doesn't use column references.

Comment: I was able to use the column reference `[Name]` in a cell formula but not in the conditional formatting formula. Is that not allowed?

Comment: I got it to work this way but it is messy because it doesn't use column references... `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,$A2,$C$2:$E$5)>7.5`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=SUMIF(Name, INDIRECT("RC[-2]", FALSE), Hours)>7.5
```

Comment: @G-J; Check the defined name ranges. Let's say above sample data in A1:C5 range then Name must be A2: A5, Hours must be C2:C5.

Answer (score 0):

The formula "something along these lines" looks very good but unfortunately [Any structured reference throws an error in CF](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/conditional-formatting-structured-references/6f51ff96-c003-4e86-829f-d7e61705e4cc).

This goes on to mention wrapping in INDIRECT. Something like this does work:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Table2[Name]"),INDIRECT("RC[-2]",FALSE),INDIRECT("Table2[Hours]"))>7.5
```

but in terms of messiness I think even worse than your messy:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,$A2,$C$2:$E$5)>7.5
```

I think @smozgur has offered an excellent "compromise" though this does involve some "behind the scenes" work. He has named the data ranges within your table as `Hours` and `Name` (hence the lack of square brackets - these are not structured references). Makes the formula look almost as you would like it but might be confusing because the range for `[Hours]` for example will automatically expand if new rows are added to the Table - but the named range `Hours` will not.

Hence my preference, assuming no conflict with data elsewhere in the columns, would be:

```
 =SUMIF(A:A,A1,C:C)>7.5
```

_ at least it is short! (But I admit I do *not* like structured references.)